# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed Request aborted

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-middleware

I am getting a 403 error while I tried most of the responses in the forum to the same problem, but no luck! This registration code is originally from tango with django site, but it is not working on django 1.10.

Any help would be appreciated, here are the files I use:

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    # Like before, get the request's context.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render_to_response(
            'heaven/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'), # ADD NEW PATTERN!
]
```

**html template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Heavenly</title>
        <style> 
        *{font-family:Arial}
        h1 {color:red;}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Register with Heavenly</h1>

        {% if registered %}
            <strong>thank you for registering!</strong>
        <a href="/home/">Return to the homepage.</a><br />
        {% else %}
            <strong>register here!</strong><br />

        <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/register/"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <!-- Display each form. The as_p method wraps each element in a paragraph
                 (<p>) element. This ensures each element appears on a new line,
                 making everything look neater. -->
            {{ user_form.as_p }}
            {{ profile_form.as_p }}

            <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10

> The dictionary and context_instance parameters for the following functions are removed:
>
> - django.shortcuts.render()
> - django.shortcuts.render_to_response()
> - django.template.loader.render_to_string()

Use `render` instead.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render